# Reloading ListView after deleting data in database from inside custom adapter (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I currently have a ListView displaying a set of items from my database using a ListView and a custom Adapter. I have also incorporated a delete button which will delete the item it is clicked on. All of this works fine, however I need to restart the app in order to see the new listview now containing the new list of data from the database. How do I fix this?

Custom Adapter:

```
package com.myurl.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import com.myurl.myapplication.R.id.itemDelete


class SQLiteListAdapter(
    context2: MainActivity,
    id: ArrayList<String>,
    name: ArrayList<String>,
    age: ArrayList<String>,
    height: ArrayList<String>
) : BaseAdapter() {
    var context: Context
    var ItemID: ArrayList<String>
    var ItemName: ArrayList<String>
    var ItemAge: ArrayList<String>
    var ItemHeight: ArrayList<String>

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ItemName.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any? {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, child: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
        var child: View? = child
        val holder: Holder
        val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater
        if (child == null) {
            layoutInflater =
                context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_item_body, null)

            // This is our delete button on each item. If the user clicks the delete button
            // we go ahead and delete it from the database
            val deleteImageView: ImageButton = child.findViewById(itemDelete) as ImageButton
            deleteImageView.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                    var myDB: SQLiteDatabase? = null

                    myDB = openOrCreateDatabase(context.getDatabasePath("Database"), null)

                    val sql = "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE item_id = ?"
                    val statement: SQLiteStatement = myDB.compileStatement(sql)

                    statement.bindString(1, ItemID[position])
                    statement.executeUpdateDelete()
                    myDB.close()
                }
            })

            holder = Holder()
            holder.textviewname = child.findViewById(R.id.itemBodyText1)
            holder.textviewage = child.findViewById(R.id.itemBodyText2)
            holder.textviewheight = child.findViewById(R.id.itemBodyText3)
            child.setTag(holder)
        } else {
            holder = child.getTag() as Holder
        }
        holder.textviewname!!.text = ItemName[position]
        holder.textviewage!!.text = ItemAge[position]
        holder.textviewheight!!.text = ItemHeight[position]
        return child
    }

    inner class Holder {
        var textviewname: TextView? = null
        var textviewage: TextView? = null
        var textviewheight: TextView? = null
    }

    init {
        context = context2
        ItemID = id
        ItemName = name
        ItemAge = age
        ItemHeight = height
    }
}
```

I want to reload either the ListView which is located in MainActivity from the Custom Adapter after I have closed the database connection.

Please note, I'm NOT deleting an item from the Adapter from the MainActivity, I'm doing it inside the Adapter, so how can I refresh the MainActivity view so that it reloads with the new data from the database?

Comment: Can you please share your all adapter code, just to see how you get items, so we can refresh it.

Comment: Yeah sorry I should've added the entire adapter @Mert , here it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a delete and refresh function in your adapter like below:

```
    fun deleteFromAllListsAndRefresh(position: Int) {
        ItemID.removeAt(position)
        ItemName.removeAt(position)
        ItemAge.removeAt(position)
        ItemHeight.removeAt(position)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

And call this function after your delete process:

```
myDB.close()
deleteFromAllListsAndRefresh(position)
```

We are doing this because your adapter doesn't know if you delete something from your db or not. We are deleting it manually from that lists and refreshing the adapter.